How to send large file via telegram bot without a virtual or a server?
my code is only sending small documents i want it to send large files ,how can i modify my code to send large files taken from my desktop and send to the user as requested without having to use virtual or telegram bot api ?

You can't do that. You have two options.

Use the Telegram API (MTProto) and build a client/userbot code to send large files through your account.

Use Bot API to send files upto 50 MB by default, or run Bot API locally and send files upto 2 GB in size.


Hope this answers.
